# Daily limit for reverse Geocoding using in Android per user?

Tags: android, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am getting the Address from the device location using the Reverse Geocoding.

I am wondering if there are any charges or per day limit. If there is any limit, does it count the number of request from each Android device? Using Geocoder provided by the google play services location.

Answer (score 0):

I see that it says that its only 2500 requests per day. Now solution is using google map API key paid after my problem is work fine and good.